# I'm a beginner with Web API, how do you overload Get when methods contains with one parameter, but parameters have various meaning. such as:

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api

ApiController:

```
public class XXXApiController : BaseApiController
{

[HttpGet]
[Route("api/patient/{phoneNumber}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetPatientsFromPhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
{
//do something
reture OK(Ret);//Ret type is User
}


[HttpGet]
[Route("api/patient/{doctorId}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetDoctorHasPatientsList(string doctorId)
{
var Ret=...
            select new
            {
            id,
            name,
            gender,
            .
            .
            .
            }
reture OK(Ret);//Ret type is List<>
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("api/patient/{currentPatientId}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetPatientHasOrdersList(string currentPatientId)
{
//do something
reture OK(Ret);//Ret type is Patient
}

}
```

View:

the following three getJSON method on one view page and urls:

```
uri="/api/patient";

$.getJSON(uri + '/' + phoneNumber) ...

$.getJSON(uri + '/' + doctorId) ...  

$.getJSON(uri + '/' + currentPatientId) ...

/api/patient/phoneNumber

/api/patient/doctorId

/api/patient/currentPatientId
```

Maybe there are better ways of implementation...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to use overload like that. Your routing rule is "api/patient/{string}" , and the web api will not know which action you want to invoke.  You should change your routing rule just like "api/controller/action" to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at route constraints. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

You could create a RegEx constraint for each.

BUT, is a doctorId distinguishable from a PatientId?

Why not instead simply call a single method using optional parameters, e.g. `/api/patient?phoneNumber=234-555-1212`?